# how to fetch small piece of information from other web site into asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic

In Classical ASP, this process can be done using the following:

```vb
Dim xml,strRetrive
set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xml.Open "GET", "http://www.abc.com/viewProduct/?productNumber="&sCode  , false
xml.Send
strRetrive=xml.responseText
```

How can we do this in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `System.Net.WebClient`:

```vb
Using c As New Net.WebClient()
    retrieved = c.DownloadString("http://www.abc.com/viewProduct/?productNumber=" & sCode)
End Using
```